# Can I prevent a particular program from showing up in the taskbar on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, taskbar

I have a program that I need to run more or less continuously, but which I won't need to access very frequently. Currently, launching the program creates a window and causes the program to appear on the taskbar. I'm fine with the program window appearing, but I'd just as soon the taskbar be reserved for programs that I need to switch between frequently—it would be superior for this program to only appear as an icon in the notification area, if at all.

Is this possible? How do I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to put a program in system tray?](http://superuser.com/questions/132661/how-to-put-a-program-in-system-tray)

Comment: While it's true that I'm not opposed to putting a program in the system tray, this question can be correctly answered in ways which that question cannot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this article: [HideIt Minimizes Any App to Your Windows System Tray](http://lifehacker.com/5813244/hideit-minimizes-any-app-to-your-windows-system-tray)

There is also  [Taskbar Hide](http://download.cnet.com/Taskbar-Hide/3000-2092_4-10302846.html)