# How to run thunderbird in system tray?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, thunderbird, notification-area, email-client

A similar question has been asked in [ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/471782/244993) but I'm working on windows 7x64 so because of using the 64 bit architecture, it seems that I can't use [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/132692/247416). Any other way?

I have set my academic email on thunderbird and I want to be instantly notified of new emails. So it should be always running on system tray

I prefer a way that requires no installation of a new software like TrayIt, ... . I will install such software just if I'm forced to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible ways to get what you want.

First, there’s the [MinimizeToTray](https://addons.mozilla.org/thunderbird/addon/minimizetotray-revived/) extension for Thunderbird. It’s available for Linux and Windows in both x86 and x64. Because I don’t use Thunderbird anymore, I don’t know if it still works.

Then, there’s [RBTray](http://rbtray.sourceforge.net/). It comes in both x86 and x64 versions. Using this tool, you can minimize any (regular) window to tray by right-clicking on the minimize window button. It runs in the background, so don’t worry when nothing happens after starting it.

Also, with x86 and x64, if it’s not about drivers, you should not look at the OS architecture but rather at your program. This is also important for RBTray. Because it injects a DLL into applications, the DLL architecture must match the application architecture. The OS architecture is not relevant at all in this case.

Comment: ok I used the first solution and it works. You should just right-click on the windows minimizing button

Comment: @sepideh If this answered your question, please accept it. Otherwise, the question will get pushed automatically. Or do you need more information?

Comment: Oh, OK. I had forgotten. This is done.

Answer (score 1):

Look like now, It's supported by Thunderbird So Go To

```
Options > (General > System Integration) check  When Thunderbird is minimized, move it to try
```

Hope this Help.

Comment: I don't see that option. The only available checkbox is: `Always check to see if Thunderbird is the default mail client on startup`

Comment: It's Windows-only